# Function add for a linked list crashes when there are more than two items in the list?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, memory, linked-list

Listed below is my add function for a templated class that uses the concept of linked lists. For some reason, having two objects in the list causes the program to crash during run-time whereas having only one item causes no issues. I've been looking at the code for a while and I still haven't managed to figure out what is wrong. I made sure to dynamically allocate memory for the new items so it's not like my pointers are pointing to garbage memory. Listed below are the struct for the MapItem and also the function add to give you guys an idea.

```
template <class keyType, class valueType>
void Map<keyType, valueType>::add(const keyType &key, const valueType &value)
{
    struct MapItem<keyType, valueType> *newItem; //create pointer to new map item
    newItem = new MapItem<keyType, valueType>; //dynamically allocate a new item on the heap
    newItem->key = key; //assign the key
    newItem->value = value; //assign the value

    if(sizeList == 0) //if linked list is empty, make newItem the HEAD
    {
        sizeList++; //increment size
        head = newItem; //set the HEAD of the list to newItem
        tail = newItem; //set the TAIL of the list to newItem
        newItem->prev = head; //previous item is the head (itself)
        newItem->next = head; //next item is the head (itself)
    }
    else //if the linked list is not empty, add it in
    {
        struct MapItem<keyType, valueType> *temp = head; //store the first element in the linked list in temp variable

        if(sizeList == 1) //if there is only one element in the list, check if they equal eachother
        {
            if(head->key != key)
            {
                tail = newItem; //assign newItem as the TAIL                
                head->next = tail; //assign the next of HEAD to the new map item
                head->prev = tail; //assign the previous of HEAD as the newItem (tail)
                tail->prev = head; //assign head to PREV of newItem (tail)
                tail->next = head; //assign HEAD to NEXT of newItem (tail)
                sizeList++; //increment size of list
            }
        //  else
        //      cout<<"Same key already exists"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            bool sameKey = false; //boolean value to check if the same key already exists, and if it does it will stop the loop
            int i = 1; //which item we are looking at in the list

            while(i <= sizeList && !sameKey) //while not past the end of the list, keep checking if a similar key exists
            {
                if(temp->key == newItem->key)
                    sameKey = true;
                else
                {
                    temp = temp->next; //go to the next map item
                    i++;
                }
            }

            if(!sameKey) //if the same key has not been found
            {
                temp->next = newItem; //assign newItem to NEXT of last node (temp) in our list
                newItem->prev = temp; //assign temp to PREV of newItem
                newItem->next = head; //assign HEAD to NEXT of newItem
                head->prev = newItem; //assign newItem to PREV of head
                tail = newItem; //assign newItem as the TAIL
                sizeList++;
            }
            else
                delete newItem; //deallocate memory of newItem
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the struct for MapItem:

```
template <class keyType, class valueType>
struct MapItem
{
    keyType key;
    valueType value;
    MapItem<keyType, valueType> *prev, *next;
};
```

Destructor:

```
template <class keyType, class valueType>
Map<keyType, valueType>::~Map()
{
    struct MapItem<keyType, valueType> *temp; //create temp variable to hold which item we are looking at in the list
    temp = head; //start at the head

    for(int i = 1; i <=sizeList; i++)
    {
        delete temp; //delete memory to pointed by temp

        if(i != sizeList) //if we are not at the last node
            temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception/error message do you get? When does it happen - when you add the second item, or the third? Which classes do you use as keyType and valueType?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I add in the second item, the program crashes as soon as I press any key to exit the program. If I create a Map and add only one MapItem, I can exit the program normally without Windows saying "Project1.exe has stopped working." 

For keyType and valueType, I have been using strings for both just to check functionality. So it would be Map<string, string> test. And then I would do say, test.add("A", "BC") which works fine, then I'll do test.add("B", "BC"), which will get added in but will cause the program to crash after.

Comment: Your destructor would seem to be relevant here. Add it to the post.

Comment: I added in the destructor, I tried removing it and compiling the code but I still ended up with the same issue.

Comment: Well you probably shouldn't access 'temp->next' after you delete 'temp', that would be a start.

Comment: `temp = temp->next;` um. you just deleted `temp` two lines earlier (and, in fact, comment on said-action: `//delete memory to pointed by temp`).

Comment: Oops, that's what happens when you code late into the hours lol. I fixed it but still the same issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Unrelated: You should probably also fix the memory leak on duplicate-avoidance. look carefully what happens when you have a list of size=1 *and* the node being inserted is a key-duplicate of that node. Hint: don't allocate a new node until you *have to* (i.e. until you *know* you're going to be inserting a new one *somewhere*).

Comment: Hey Craig, yeah I already knew about that haha. I got lazy so I just added in the delete newItem at the bottom as a temporary fix. Thanks though for pointing that out!

Comment: Well, that temporary fix doesn't fix what I just described. It only comes into play if `sizeList > 1`, which contradicts what I just said. I'm also confused why you need a head *and* tail pointer in a circular linked list. If the intent is to *not* be circular it makes sense to have a tail, otherwise its meaningless.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, I just added the delete up there too as an else condition but still the same issue. Well my professor had given us this the header file with everything defined and told us to do a doubly-linked list with a head and tail, so I'm just following his way for the sake of the grade even though you are right.

Comment: Were the specific instructions to manufacture a double-linked list, or a *circular* double-linked list. The former (which finds a tail-pointer quite-helpful) is considerably easier to manage than the latter (which  requires no tail pointer as you already have one (`head->prev`)).

Comment: He had said circular in class, it is possible he may have been mistaken himself  as someone else writes out our project outlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it - replace the line

```
temp->next = newItem; //assign newItem to NEXT of last node (temp) in our list
```

with

```
tail->next = newItem; //assign newItem to NEXT of last node (temp) in our list
```

because when you loop through the items looking for the key, you get back to head - so 'temp' points to 'head' after the loop is finished. But you want to add at the end.

Until this change I did get a memory access violation during destruction (even though I do not understand why you still got some error after you removed the destructor code).

Destructor code for clarity:

```
~Map()
{
    struct MapItem<keyType, valueType> *temp; //create temp variable to hold which item we are looking at in the list
    temp = head; //start at the head

    for(int i = 1; i <=sizeList; i++)
    {
        MapItem<keyType, valueType> *next = temp->next;

        delete temp; //delete memory to pointed by temp

        if(i != sizeList) //if we are not at the last node
            temp = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, give me one moment while I try it out, thanks!

Comment: Okay, I added it in and fixed the logic but still the same issue...Let's just say I'm never going to code late at night again lol.

Comment: I don't know then... With the fixed destructor (I added that for clarity) I stopped getting the problem...

Comment: Okay, it's working now! I had to rebuild the solution, exit, and re-open and now it's working fine. Visual Studio getting weird on me... but that was the fix man, thanks so much! You don't know how long I was stuck on this lol. I ended up coding 3 classes like this in the middle of the night hence why my logic was off at times. How can I thank you in a better way??